# sorting list of indices

Tags: python, sorting

How do I sort a list of indices by what they're pointing to in python?

I have

```
 indices = list(range(len(mylist)))
```

I want to sort the indices so that if `a` precedes `b` in indices then `mylist[a] > mylist[b]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.6+, most elegant answer:

```
indices.sort(key = lambda x:mylist[x], reverse = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
indicies.sort(lambda x,y:mylist[x]-mylist[y])
```

Comment: Also, what if mylist is a list of numpy floats?  Then, I need an integer-returning sign function.  Is `int(numpy.sign(...))` the best I can do?

Comment: Keep in mind P3K is a little different, http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/ has more info if you're interested

Comment: This worked: `indices.sort(key = lambda x:mylist[x], reverse = True)`

Answer (score 1):

Also, let me add the following snippet as an answer, using the information provided in your original question...

> I want to sort the indices so that if
>   a precedes b in indices then mylist[a] > mylist[b].

...and the additional info you have in your comment

> Also, what if mylist is a list of
>   numpy floats?

Then you can simply do:

```
In [2]: import numpy

In [3]: a = numpy.asarray([-1, 2.73, 15.827, -8.48, 9, 13, 15, 3.22, 0, -1, 1])

In [4]: indices = a.argsort()[::-1]
Out[4]: array([ 2,  6,  5,  4,  7,  1, 10,  8,  9,  0,  3])

In [5]: a[indices]
Out[5]: 
array([ 15.827,  15.   ,  13.   ,   9.   ,   3.22 ,   2.73 ,   1.   ,
     0.   ,  -1.   ,  -1.   ,  -8.48 ])
```